# Multi-level recursion using SQL Server CTE with aggregation at each level

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to run a recursive query to propagate the value in column `Quantity` level by level in the following table:

```
create table propagate 
(
    parent varchar(50), 
    child varchar(50), 
    level int, 
    quantity int
);

insert into propagate values ('A','B',0,100);
insert into propagate values ('AA','B',0,100);
insert into propagate values ('A','C',0,100);
insert into propagate values ('AA','C',0,100);
insert into propagate values ('B','C',1,100);
insert into propagate values ('C',NULL,2,100);
```

| parent | child | level | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 0 | 100 |
| AA | B | 0 | 100 |
| A | C | 0 | 100 |
| AA | C | 0 | 100 |
| B | C | 1 | 100 |
| C | NULL | 2 | 100 |

The intention is to first sum up all values in column quantity for those records where level = 0 and then copy that value as propagated_qty for the records in next level, which is level = 1.

As the next step, the quantity of level 1 and quantity of level 0 propagated to level 1 should add up and then be propagated to level 2 and so on. I wrote a cte for the same:

```
;with cte(parent, child, level, quantity) as
(
    select  a.parent, 
            a.child,
            a.level,
            a.quantity
    from propagate as a
    where a.level = 0
    union all
    select  y.parent,
            y.child,
            y.level,
            y.quantity + x.quantity
            from cte x inner join propagate y
            on x.child = y.parent
            and x.level < 10
)
select * from cte;
```

At this point, the output is the following:

| parent | child | level | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 0 | 100 |
| AA | B | 0 | 100 |
| A | C | 0 | 100 |
| AA | C | 0 | 100 |
| C | NULL | 2 | 200 |
| C | NULL | 2 | 200 |
| B | C | 1 | 200 |
| C | NULL | 2 | 300 |
| B | C | 1 | 200 |
| C | NULL | 2 | 300 |

The problem with this is that I am not able aggregate the quantity at each level before passing it on to the next level. When I try to do aggregation within cte, its throwing the following error:

> GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression

Is there a way to do this aggregation at each level and iterate through the different levels within the CTE?

Also, since I am using union all, same parent-child combination is getting repeated multiple times. Hence, I am not able aggregate the quantity at each level correctly. Kindly let me know if there is a solution to this as well?

Desired output is the following:

| parent | child | level | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 0 | 100 |
| AA | B | 0 | 100 |
| A | C | 0 | 100 |
| AA | C | 0 | 100 |
| B | C | 1 | 300 |
| C | NULL | 2 | 500 |

Comment: Please let me know how I can insert tables here via text

Comment: What is the desired output from your sample data?

Comment: I have added the desired output @SeanLange

Comment: What is this supposed to do?  I can see a parent child in the table, but to have a level as well is confusing.  Why is there a record with a null child?

Comment: The last input record for C to a NULL child.  Should the quantity be 0 for no xfer amount to a child?  It's there just to get a record out of the cte?

Comment: The Null value is there because it is the final level. The quantity should not be 0

Comment: @Hariprasad B gets 200 directly from A/AA.  C gets 100 directly B plus 200 indirectly for the 300.  Then C gets 200 directly from A/AA and 300 from B for a total of 500.  The record with the NULL shows C giving null 100.  This plus the 500 is 600?  I can't help but feel something is not right.

Comment: Also, in the original data, is the level how many parents exist for the parent?  If so, it does not need to be given to do the calculation.